# When two numbers of a certain form are coprime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I am dealing with some $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and want to know when the numbers $(r + 2)$ and $(r - 1)$ are coprime. When these two numbers are coprime then $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $(r + 2)x + (r - 1)y = 1$. Is there a general algebraic way to find all solutions for $(x, y)$ without using something like Fermat's Little Theorem? Maybe something related to Bezout's Theorem?

Comment: Any common divisor of $r+2$ and $r-1$ is a divisor of their difference which is $3$, hence they are relatively prime unless $r\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ in which case their gcd is $3$.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine when $\,f(r), g(r)\,$ are coprime for any polynomials $\,f,g\,$ with integer coefficients, or only for the given particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(r+2)$ and $(r-1)$ are coprime if $r$ is not congruent to $1$ $\mod 3$

Indeed $GCD(r+2,r-1)=GCD(r-1,3)$ thus if $r-1$ is a multiple of $3$ then $GCD\ne 1$

Now suppose that $r\equiv 0\mod 3$ that is $r=3k$

The equation becomes

$$(3k+2)x+(3k-1)y=1$$
Whose solution are
$$x=h (3 k-1)+k;\;y=h -k-1-(3 k+2));\;\forall h\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Suppose $r\equiv 2\mod 3$, that is $r=3k-1$

The equation becomes
$$(3k+1)x+(3k-2)y=1$$
Whose solutions are
$$x=h (3 k-2)+2 k-1,\;y=h (-(3 k+1))-2 k-1;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a nice solution.